# reference Request.Browser with fully qualified name MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, request, httprequest

if Request is inside the System.Web.Mav namespace, in the Controller class (see below the autogenerated structure with F12),
 why am I not able to reference it with the fully qualified name

```
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Request.Browser`

namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public abstract class Controller : ControllerBase, IActionFilter, IAuthorizationFilter, IDisposable, IExceptionFilter, IResultFilter, IAsyncController, IController, IAsyncManagerContainer
    {
        protected Controller();
        ....
        public HttpRequestBase Request { get; }
        ....
    }
}
```

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and C#
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because this `Request` property is an instance property of `Controller`, not a static one.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        //you can access this.Request.Browser 
        //because "this" gives an instance of Controller

        //you can't use System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Request.Browser 
        //because "Request" is not a static property of "Controller"
    }
}
```

To make it simpler, consider this:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; }
}

//Person.Name   -> invalid, "Name" property is not static
//new Person().Name    -> valid, "Name" property is access via an instance of "Person"
```